# Does a Medic's Weapon's action include the extra channel divinity action?

Tags: dnd-4e, actions

A character with the *Channel Divinity* class feature will have a set of associated *channel divinity* powers that may range from free actions to standard actions. They usually may only use one such power per encounter. The *Medic's Weapon*, however, includes this daily power:

> Power | Daily (Standard Action)
>   Gain one additional use of Channel Divinity for this encounter.

I can't tell from the wording whether this means:

1. Use the medic's weapon's daily to gain an additional use of *Channel Divinity*, but actually using your bonus channel divinity power is a separate action (possibly free, possibly standard, depending on the power); **or**
2. Use the medic's weapon's daily to gain an additional use of *Channel Divinity*, using the chosen power as part of this action.

Which is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading it straight, it appears to cost a standard action to give you a "free" Channel Divinity that must be used before the end of the encounter or be lost.  It does not appear to automatically use that Channel nor give you an action to allow you to do so, so you must spend another action to activate it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a separate action to use the Channel Divinity.

Let's say you're playing a Paladin who has *Channel Divinity: Divine Strength* which is a Minor Action.
Round 1 - Minor Action to use *CD: Divine Strength* + Standard Action to attack

Round 2 - Standard Action to use the Medic's Weapon Daily and gain a second use of Channel Divinity + Minor Action to use *Channel Divinity* again + Action Point + Standard Action to attack